# How to detect Type/Modality of Lync Conversation?

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I need to check whether the conversation is an audio call or a chat.
The check needs to happen at the moment the ConversationManager_ConversationAdded Event is triggered.

```
        private void InitialisiereLyncClient()
        {
            //(Running Lync instance)
            m_LyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
            ConversationManager m_ConversationManager = m_LyncClient.ConversationManager;


            m_ConversationManager.ConversationAdded += M_ConversationManager_ConversationAdded;
            m_ConversationManager.ConversationRemoved += M_ConversationManager_ConversationRemoved; 
        }
```

Here i would like to check what kind of Conversation it is to handle future actions.

```
        //Eigenschaften der Conversation
        IDictionary<ConversationProperty, object> m_properties = e.Conversation.Properties;

        //Informationen der Person, die das Event ausgelöst hat
        Contact m_caller = e.Conversation.Properties[ConversationProperty.Inviter] as Contact;
```

**Question:**
How can i distinguish whether the conversation is an Audio/Video call or a Chat conversation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works.

```
        bool hasAVModality = e.Conversation.Modalities.ContainsKey(ModalityTypes.AudioVideo);
        if (hasAVModality)
        {
            //State of AV modality
            var state = e.Conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].State;
            //Notified = Incoming
            if (state == ModalityState.Notified)
            {
                //Do Something with the call
            }
        }
```